# Can't call Luis in Azure bot framework

Tags: azure, .net-core, botframework, azure-language-understanding

[image]I am a noob in dotnet as well as on Luis and bot framework.

I am trying to make some bot samples work on my machine from

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples.

I am interested in this one particularly in

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/13.core-bot

When i run the bot, it does not connect to Luis (see error message below).

- I created and published an app in Luis by importing the intent supplied in the app.
- I wrote LuisAppId,LuisAPIKey and LuisAPIHostName in the correct JSON file (see below).
- I added the dotnet library to the project : dotnet add package Cognitive.LUIS.Programmatic

I then just run the code with the `cmd "dotnet run"` in the correct folder.

Here the *app.setting* JSON. I used subscription-key as LuisAPIKey, and app ID as LuisAppId.

```
{
  "MicrosoftAppId": "",
  "MicrosoftAppPassword": "",
  "LuisAppId": "2aa2b9c5-#######################7b557",
  "LuisAPIKey": "1069d###############4347da9",
  "LuisAPIHostName": "westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/api/v2.0"
}
```

The bot is running on my localhost. But it just does not work.

> bot : What can I help you with today? Say something like “Book a
>   flight from Paris to Berlin on March 22, 2020”
>
> me : “Please Book a flight from Paris to Berlin on March 22, 2020”
>
> bot :"The bot encounted an error or bug."
>
> bot :"To continue to run this bot, please fix the bot source code"

```
On the cmd line : 
"fail: Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Integration.AspNet.Core.BotFrameworkHttpAdapter[0]
      [OnTurnError] unhandled error : Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.Models.APIErrorException: Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'
   at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.Prediction.ResolveWithHttpMessagesAsync(String appId, String query, Nullable`1 timezoneOffset, Nullable`1 verbose, Nullable`1 staging, Nullable`1 spellCheck, String bingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey, Nullable`1 log, Dictionary`2 customHeaders, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Azure.CognitiveServices.Language.LUIS.Runtime.PredictionExtensions.ResolveAsync(IPrediction operations, String appId, String query, Nullable`1 timezoneOffset, Nullable`1 verbose, Nullable`1 staging, Nullable`1 spellCheck, String bingSpellCheckSubscriptionKey, Nullable`1 log, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis.LuisRecognizer.RecognizeInternalAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, LuisPredictionOptions predictionOptions, Dictionary`2 telemetryProperties, Dictionary`2 telemetryMetrics, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.LUIS\LuisRecognizer.cs:line 345
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.Luis.LuisRecognizer.RecognizeAsync[T](ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.AI.LUIS\LuisRecognizer.cs:line 163
   at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.FlightBookingRecognizer.RecognizeAsync[T](ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\flabare\botbuilder-samples\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\13.core-bot\FlightBookingRecognizer.cs:line 38
   at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Dialogs.MainDialog.ActStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\flabare\botbuilder-samples\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\13.core-bot\Dialogs\MainDialog.cs:line 67
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.OnStepAsync(WaterfallStepContext stepContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\WaterfallDialog.cs:line 166
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.RunStepAsync(DialogContext dc, Int32 index, DialogReason reason, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\WaterfallDialog.cs:line 188
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.WaterfallDialog.ResumeDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, DialogReason reason, Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\WaterfallDialog.cs:line 113
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.EndDialogAsync(Object result, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\DialogContext.cs:line 196
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Prompt`1.ContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext dc, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\Prompts\Prompt.cs:line 147
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\DialogContext.cs:line 160
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.ComponentDialog.ContinueDialogAsync(DialogContext outerDc, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\ComponentDialog.cs:line 84
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogContext.ContinueDialogAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\DialogContext.cs:line 160
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.DialogExtensions.RunAsync(Dialog dialog, ITurnContext turnContext, IStatePropertyAccessor`1 accessor, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs\DialogExtensions.cs:line 18
   at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Bots.DialogBot`1.OnMessageActivityAsync(ITurnContext`1 turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\flabare\botbuilder-samples\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\13.core-bot\Bots\DialogBot.cs:line 48
   at Microsoft.BotBuilderSamples.Bots.DialogBot`1.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\Users\flabare\botbuilder-samples\samples\csharp_dotnetcore\13.core-bot\Bots\DialogBot.cs:line 36
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotFrameworkAdapter.TenantIdWorkaroundForTeamsMiddleware.OnTurnAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, NextDelegate next, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotFrameworkAdapter.cs:line 995
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.MiddlewareSet.ReceiveActivityWithStatusAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\MiddlewareSet.cs:line 55
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.BotAdapter.RunPipelineAsync(ITurnContext turnContext, BotCallbackHandler callback, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in d:\a\1\s\libraries\Microsoft.Bot.Builder\BotAdapter.cs:line 167"
```

As mentioned I am new to this, so any insights on the above would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in your `appsettings.json`. You need your `LuisAPIHostName` to be only `westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com`. If that doesn't work, try just `westus`. The sample has changed frequently and we plan on standardizing it across all of the samples and documentation once LUIS releases their new API endpoints.

[Here's the instructions in the Sample README](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/pull/1083)

[Here's a Pull Request noting how common this issue is](https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-js/pull/1083)

Edit: As @vikasramereddi mentioned below, you also need to make sure your LUIS app is published to Production and not Staging.

Comment: It works like a charm with "westus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com". Thank you!

Comment: In addition, you should remove the `Cognitive.LUIS.Programmatic` package that you added which is useless in your case

Comment: Faced the same issue mentioned in the question. For me, issue happened because I published my Luis service in staging it should be published in production